# Putting Debug.log as a GUI element in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My program currently displays text in the console.

I want this text to be displayed in the game window.

The data is part of a web request.

Is there a simple way of displaying what appears in the console as a GUI element?

Comment: I suggest you should check on [Unity UI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can simply add a callback to e.g. [`Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceivedThreaded.html)

Example from the API extended with `OnGUI` script from [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/654880/how-do-i-create-a-text-box-to-display-scrollable-t.html)

```
// Put this on any GameObject in the scene
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Adjust via the Inspector
    public int maxLines = 8;
    private Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
    private string currentText = "";

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded -= HandleLog;
    }

    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        // Delete oldest message
        if (queue.Count >= maxLines) queue.Dequeue();

        queue.Enqueue(logString);

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string st in queue)
        {
            builder.Append(st).Append("\n");
        }

        currentText = builder.ToString();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(
           new Rect(
               5,                   // x, left offset
               Screen.height - 150, // y, bottom offset
               300f,                // width
               150f                 // height
           ),      
           currentText,             // the display text
           GUI.skin.textArea        // use a multi-line text area
        );
    }
}
```

---

In general: `OnGUI` is kind of legacy and you should really only use this for debugging.

But you can basically use the same script also for e.g. a [`UI.Text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html) component and instead of using `OnGUI` assign the text to it.

The script would basically look the same but have a

```
public Text text;
```

and instead of `OnGUI` would directly do

```
text.text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the font bigger? It's so small I can't read anything. Otherwise seems to work great. Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I solved it with GUI.skin.textArea.fontSize = 40; just before the GUI Label function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[DotPlay](https://github.com/matinmn87/unity-dotplay) also has a good solution for it. this is the example code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using DotPlay;

public class Class1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start ()
    {
        DebugAgent.LogGUI ("Hello!");
        DebugAgent.LogGUI ("Bye!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer for 2023 using TextMeshPro, derived from derHugo's answer

`DebugLogCanvas.cs`

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class DebugLogCanvas : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int maxLines = 50;
    [SerializeField] TextMeshProUGUI debugLogText;

    Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();

    void OnEnable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded -= HandleLog;
    }

    void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        // Delete oldest message
        if (queue.Count >= maxLines) queue.Dequeue();

        queue.Enqueue(logString);

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string st in queue)
        {
            builder.Append(st).Append("\n");
        }

        debugLogText.text = builder.ToString();
    }
}
```