# Is it possible to show whatever is printed in the Debug.Log into the scene using a text?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert the messages that appear in the unity console, in text inside the scene.

Do you have suggestions how to do it ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html to get the messages, then keep track of what you want to display, build a UI for it, and display it.

Comment: This should answer your question [Putting Debug.log as a GUI element in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228993/putting-debug-log-as-a-gui-element-in-unity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Putting Debug.log as a GUI element in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228993/putting-debug-log-as-a-gui-element-in-unity)

Comment: Make sure you review previous questions to prevent asking duplicate questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Debug.Log() you are already giving it a value or text to be shown in the console, so you can take that value and display it in a text object.

Comment: In my case is a little bit different because the text I need to show in UI interface is related to instruction and feedback about BLE connect process, for this reason is better read directly the console and display information on the interface

Comment: I see, you did not mention that in your question,

Answer (score -1):

This code work in part, because now it shows me text that appear in console, but get only the first text, and then the other sentences are queued to be shown but this never happens because only the first sentence is shown.

```
enter code here

void OnEnable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += HandleLog;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded -= HandleLog;
}

void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    if (type == LogType.Log){
        string[] splitString = logString.Split(char.Parse(":"));
        string debugKey = splitString[0];
        string debugValue = splitString.Length > 1 ? splitString[1] :"";

        if (debugLogs.ContainsKey(debugKey))
            debugLogs[debugKey] = debugValue;
             else
             debugLogs.Add(debugKey, debugValue);

             
  }

  string displayText = "";
  foreach ( KeyValuePair<string, string> log in debugLogs)
  {
      if(log.Value ==""){
      displayText += log.Key + "\n ";
      }


      else{
       displayText += log.Key + ": " + log.Value + "\n";
       }

    }
            
    display.text = displayText;

}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.